# Get at properties from within properties of the same class

Tags: python, django

I've got a class in my django app models.py and I would like to define properties using other properties, like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):

    @property
    def Bar(self):
        return 3

    @property
    def Baz(self):
        return self.Bar(self) + 4
```

So in the template

```
{{ f.Baz }}
```

Would render

```
7
```

Comment: And it is not working? What problem are you getting?

Comment: It's not working. It won't render anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not pass `self` as a parameter, just do this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):

    @property
    def Bar(self):
        return 3

    @property
    def Baz(self):
        return self.Bar + 4 # Bar is a property
```

Comment: I ended up taking off the parenthesis as well and it worked. `self.Bar + 4`

Comment: @broinjc, Congrats, I wasn't really much help. :P

Comment: You put me on the path to great success! :)